# How do I determine the UUID at the time of record creation and pass it as an argument to the function in another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pretty simple table called `books` with two columns. In the second column (`book_name`), I want to set the default value that would be formed by the specific function. Is it possible to pass the `UUID` of the first column (`book_id`) to this function at the time of record creation?

**SQL**:

```
create extension if not exists "uuid-ossp";

create table books (
    book_id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4() primary key,
    book_name varchar not null
);
```

I tried to set default value to the second column with the next statement:

```
alter table only books alter column book_name set default generate_book_name(uuid_generate_v4());
```

This didn't work as expected, since the function `uuid_generate_v4()` generates a different UUID each time.

Comment: I think a trigger is your only option. Btw: in case you are using Postgres 13, you don't need the `uuid-ossp` extension any more to generate UUIDs

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the information. Well, in fact, my PostgreSQL database vesion is: `PostgreSQL 12.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no need to alter the column. You can use `WITH` clause for your requirement. Just write your insert query like below:

```
with cte as (
select uuid_generate_v4() as uuid_
)
insert into books 
select uuid_, generate_book_name(uuid_) from cte;
```

**OR**

Write a trigger as suggested by  `a_horse_with_no_name` like below:

Trigger Function:

```
create or replace function trig_books() returns trigger
as
$$
begin
new.book_name=generate_book_name(new.book_id);
return NEW;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

Trigger

```
create trigger trig_book 
before insert on books
for each row execute procedure trig_books();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The second variant which you described is exactly what I was looking for.